# Remove "Act as part of the operating system" policy

Tags: security, user-permissions, group-policy

On one of our servers we have enabled the "Act as part of the operating system" policy in the Local Security Policy. (Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment).

Now we would like to remove this user, but when I go to the properties of that policy, the Remove button is always disabled.

How can this policy be set to default again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the system run "rsop.msc" from the command prompt and navigate in the MMC window to the setting. It will tell you where it is set, it's probably being defined in a Group Policy.

You will need to edit that GPO to remove the setting.

Comment: Thanks, I found it via that rsop.msc command in the "Group Policy Management Editor > Default Domain Policy > Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment" !